# use tsql to detect XML dependency

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql, xsd

i have a XML schema bound to a table.  however, sometimes testers piggyback and bind to this schema too.  when there is this "ninja" XML table reference, any alteration to this schema is painful.

i'd like to run a query before schema altering and raise exception if the XML schema is bound to more than one table.  i've looked at sys.sql_dependencies and few of the other sys.xml_XXXX tables, but it's not clear how to do this in tsql.  is something like this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might be helpful

```
select object_name(object_id) as TableName, 
       col_name(object_id, column_id) as ColumnName
from sys.column_xml_schema_collection_usages as U
  inner join sys.xml_schema_collections as S
    on U.xml_collection_id = S.xml_collection_id
where S.name = 'YourXMLSchemaCollectionName'
```

This one is to find where the schema is used in a XML parameter.

```
select object_name(object_id) 
from sys.parameter_xml_schema_collection_usages as P
  inner join sys.xml_schema_collections as S
    on P.xml_collection_id = S.xml_collection_id
where S.name = 'YourXMLSchemaCollectionName'
```